# List (T) Databinding at Design Time

Tags: .net, list, data-binding, datagridview

It's possible to bind the list to a data grid at runtime, like `DataGridView.DataSource = MyList`.

But it would be great to bind it at design time, so columns auto-population would work.

Is there any possibility of binding the list at design time? I know there's another class, `BindingList`, but not sure how to bind it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using WinForms here.

You can't directly bind to a `List<T>`, as there's no way to reference that object at design time (it's not a component). You can, however, use the designer and bind to the specific list at runtime. To do this, you'll want to create a `BindingSource` component on your form, then bind it to the type of object that you want to display. At runtime, set the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` to your `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can,

Click on Anchor on design of GridView

Select Datasources

Click on Add ProjectDatasource

Select **OBJECT**

Select your project

Select Class